# Vagrant con VirtualBox, optimización de un script de Laboratorio. DNS, IP, PROVISION, etc

Tags: shell-script, dns, virtualbox, vagrant

A continuación os muestro el script que he preparado para un taller de pruebas. En él habrá varias máquinas virtuales, un par de **clientes**, y varios servicios **apache** y **nginx**, y un servidor de **dns**.
Todos ellos habrá que configurarlos y todos deben resolver con el servidor de dns.

El script funciona perfectamente con `vagrant up`, pero me gustaría que tardase menos tiempo en levantarse, ya que todas las máquinas son iguales, excepto la `provision` que establece la ip.

Preguntas:

- ¿Se puede optimizar la creación de las máquinas virtuales, de tal manera que no tengan que comiplar las `guest additions` cada vez que se crea una máquina?
- ¿Existe alguna manera de configurar la interfaza de red, con ip, dns, gateway y dominio desde comandos vagrant? Sólo he podio mediante el script que véis.
- ¿Habría alguna manera de optimizar el código Ruby? Estoy seguro que así es. Soy nuevo en vagrant y me está resultando complicado.
- Para organizarlas máquinas las añado a un grupo de VirtualBox, pero `vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/DWEB"]` no me está funcionando.
- Todas las máquinas están en la red `192.168.56.0/21`, que he visto es la que VirtualBox predetermina para `red privada`. ¿Es así? No obstante me añade un adaptador NAT a cada máqina. ¿?
- Establezco un red privada con `auto_config: false` para poder "*arreglar*" el direccionamiento con el provisionado. ¿Se puede hacer de otra manera?
- El aprovisionamiento está preparado para que cada servicio tenga su propio aprovisionamiento. En la variable $provision. Podría haber un distinto por cada servicio. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo mejor?

```rb
BOX_IMAGE = "ubuntu/focal64"
DOMAIN = "aula104"

$setnetwork = <<-'SHELL'
sudo su
HOSTIP=$1
FILE=/etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yaml
DOMAIN=aula104
DNSIP=192.168.56.99
cat <<\EOF >$FILE
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - HOSTIP/21
      gateway4: 192.168.56.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - DNSIP
        search:
        - DOMAIN
  version: 2
EOF
sed -i "s/HOSTIP/$HOSTIP/g" $FILE
sed -i "s/DOMAIN/$DOMAIN/g" $FILE
sed -i "s/DNSIP/$DNSIP/g" $FILE
echo -e nameserver $DNSIP\\nsearch $DOMAIN >/etc/resolv.conf
systemctl stop systemd-resolved 
netplan apply
sleep 5
SHELL

$provision = <<-'SHELL'
sudo su
echo provisioning
SHELL

services = {
  "nginx"   => { :ip => "192.168.56.10", :provision=>$provision },
  "apache1" => { :ip => "192.168.56.11", :provision=>$provision },
  "apache2" => { :ip => "192.168.56.12", :provision=>$provision },
  "dns"     => { :ip => "192.168.56.99", :provision=>$provision },
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Common config
  config.vm.box = BOX_IMAGE
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.161",  netmask: "255.255.248.0",  auto_config: false
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.memory = 1024
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/DWEB"]
  end

  # client #1
  config.vm.define :client do |guest|
    guest.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, subconfig|
      vb.name = "client"
      subconfig.vm.hostname = "client.#{DOMAIN}"
    end
    guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setnetwork, args: "192.168.56.16"
  end

  # client #2
  config.vm.define :client2 do |guest|
    guest.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, subconfig|
      vb.name = "client2"
      subconfig.vm.hostname = "client2.#{DOMAIN}"
    end
    guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setnetwork, args: "192.168.56.17"
  end

  # services
  services.each_with_index do |(hostname, info), index|
    config.vm.define hostname do |guest|
      guest.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb, subconfig|
        vb.name = hostname
        subconfig.vm.hostname = "#{hostname}.#{DOMAIN}"
      end # end provider
      guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setnetwork, args: "#{info[:ip]} #{hostname}"
      guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: info[:provision]
    end # end config
  end #
end
```

P.D: Es un trabajo en curso.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Pues despues de dar muchas vueltas, y haber aprendido mucho, tengo un script que: levanta y configura un DNS/DCHP con `nsmasq`, tres servicios (a configurar por vosotros), léase dos `apache` y un `nginx`, y dos clientes DCHP. Los servicios y los clientes, resuelven las direcciones de internet atraveś del dns.

Este es el script:

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
BOX_IMAGE = "ubuntu/focal64"
DOMAIN = "aula104"
DNSIP = "192.168.56.100"

$provision = <<-SHELL
  echo provisioning $1 ...
  apt-get update
SHELL

$dnsclient = <<-SHELL
  DNSIP=$1
  apt-get update
  systemctl disable --now systemd-resolved
  systemctl stop systemd-resolved
  echo -e "nameserver $DNSIP">/etc/resolv.conf
  dig google.com +short
  ping -c 1 dns
SHELL

services = {
  "nginx"   => { :ip => "192.168.56.10", :provision=>$provision },
  "apache1" => { :ip => "192.168.56.11", :provision=>$provision },
  "apache2" => { :ip => "192.168.56.12", :provision=>$provision },
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # config general
  config.vm.box = BOX_IMAGE
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.memory = 1024
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/DWEB"]
  end

  # dns 
  config.vm.define :dns do |guest|
    guest.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, subconfig|
      vb.name = "dns"
      subconfig.vm.hostname = "dns.#{DOMAIN}"
      subconfig.vm.network :private_network, ip: DNSIP, virtualbox__intnet: "redinterna"
    end
    guest.vm.provision "shell", path: "enable-dnsmasq.sh", args: DNSIP
  end

  # services 
  services.each_with_index do |(hostname, info), index|
    config.vm.define hostname do |guest|
      guest.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb, subconfig|
        vb.name = hostname
        subconfig.vm.hostname = "#{hostname}.#{DOMAIN}"
        subconfig.vm.network :private_network, ip: info[:ip], virtualbox__intnet: "redinterna"
      end
      guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: $dnsclient, args: DNSIP
      guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: info[:provision], args: hostname
    end 
  end
  
  # clients DHCP
  (16..17).each_with_index do |ip4, i|
    id = i + 1
    config.vm.define "client#{id}" do |guest|
      guest.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, subconfig|
        vb.name = "client#{id}"
        subconfig.vm.hostname = "client#{id}.#{DOMAIN}"
        subconfig.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp", virtualbox__intnet: "redinterna"
      end
      guest.vm.provision "shell", inline: $dnsclient, args: DNSIP
    end
  end

end
```

¡Tarda en levantar todo 17 minutos! Pero bueno, creo que es mejor que hacer las máquinas virtuales a mano.

En respuesta a mis propias preguntas:

1. ¿Se puede optimizar la creación de las máquinas virtuales, de tal
   manera que no tengan que compilar las guest additions cada vez que
   se crea una máquina?

   - No he encontrado la manera (todavía). Aunque he leído sobre **Linked Clones**.
2. ¿Existe alguna manera de configurar la interfaza de red, con ip, dns, gateway y dominio desde comandos vagrant? Sólo he podio
   mediante el script que véis.

   - No. Es mejor no tocar la configuración de red, y dejar que vagrant lo haga por tí.
   - MUY IMPORTANTE: Nonbrar la red, Si quito `virtualbox__intnet: "redinterna"` el cliente DHCP no va a saber a que red se debe conectar ya que VB crea una con las IP's proporcionadas.
3. ¿Habría alguna manera de optimizar el código Ruby? Estoy seguro que
   así es. Soy nuevo en vagrant y me está resultando complicado.

   - Y soy nuevo en Ruby. No me parece que haya ninguna manera más óptima.
4. Para organizarlas máquinas las añado a un grupo de VirtualBox, pero `vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/DWEB"]` no me está
   funcionando.

   - Cerrando y volviendo a abrir la interfaz de VirtualBOx aparece correcto.
5. Todas las máquinas están en la red 192.168.56.0/21, que he visto es la que VirtualBox predetermina para red privada. ¿Es así? No
   obstante me añade un adaptador NAT a cada máqina. ¿?

- Tambien funciona con máscara 24. El adaptador NAT, no he querido quitarlo ya que por ahí salen a internet

6. Establezco un red privada con auto_config: false para poder "arreglar" el direccionamiento con el provisionado. ¿Se puede hacer
   de otra manera?

   - Es una pregunta de novato. Esta respuesta dice que sí.
7. El aprovisionamiento está preparado para que cada servicio tenga su propio aprovisionamiento. En la variable $provision. Podría haber
   un distinto por cada servicio. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo mejor?

   - No lo veo

Mejoras:

- Poner una máquina router virtual y quitar la NAT. Eso sería de PRO

Comment: no se yo si te convendria aprender [ansible](https://www.redhat.com/es/technologies/management/ansible) para estas cosas, lo dejo como idea. Enlaces que te pueden interesar: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_vagrant.html  , https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/